# RxJava Single.just in main thread

Tags: java, android, rx-java

This code begining in main thread, but i use `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` on `Schedulers.io`

```
  disposableBag.add(Single.just(HardOperation.get())
            .doOnSuccess(it -> {
                Log.i("123", Thread.currentThread() + " current"); // Thread[RxCachedThreadScheduler-1,5,main]
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(it -> {
                adapter.set(it);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }));
```

if i use this sample

```
disposableBag.add(Single
                .create((SingleOnSubscribe<List<Info>>) emitter -> {
                    emitter.onSuccess(HardOperation.get());
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(it -> {
                    adapter.set(it);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }));
```

it works nice

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: @BorisSafonov Why when i use `.just` it's does in main thread?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking why `HardOperation.get()` runs on main thread when called inside `Single.just()`.

The reason is you are creating a `Single` (subclass of `Observable`) using `Single.just()`. The code is evaluated from inside out, from inner most expression out. So, `HardOperation.get()` is called first before being passed to `Single.just()`. `HardOperation.get()` will then take a while to complete and block the entire programs execution, before RxJava has a chance to do work on a different thread.

The difference of the second code snippet is that `Single.create((SingleOnSubscribe<List<Info>>) emitter -> {emitter.onSuccess(HardOperation.get());})` creates a `Single` by taking in an object that **produces** or **emits** a `HardOperation.get()`. Creating this **producer** object is fast. Notice that `emitter.onSuccess(HardOperation.get())` is not immediately called. 
The producer is created and given to `Single.create()`. It is RxJava's job to call the producer wrapped in the `Single` on a different thread, which then calls `HardOperation.get()` without blocking.

Comment: good answer! According to the example in question, i'd recommend to use `Single.fromCallable {}` instead of `Single.just()`